# pandas multiIndex restructuring DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, multi-index

After grouping procedure for DataFrame, I have table structured this way:

```
                sum     count
endAt       id      
2021-01-02  628 100.0   1
2021-01-03  628 300.0   1
2021-01-06  32  100.0   1
2021-01-07  629 50.0    1
2021-01-08  619 150.0   2
... ... ... ...
2021-04-22  860 100.0   2
            861 150.0   2
            869 350.0   6
            876 100.0   1
            883 200.0   4
```

Tried to pivot table but stuck with re-indexing the structure.
is a way to restructure DataFrame with following indexes:

```
colums = pd.MultiIndex.from_product([['2021-01-01', '2021-01-02', ....],['sum','count']], names=['date','types'])
index = pd.MltiIndex.from_product([32,619,628,....],names=['id'])
```

and get DataFrame structured like:

```
id      endAt       2021-01-02  2021-01-02
                    sum count   sum count
32                  100 1       200 2
619                 0   0       100 1
628                 300 3       0   0
...........
883                 100 1       200 2
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need [`DataFrame.unstack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.unstack.html) by first level, then swap levels in `MultiIndex` and sorting:

```
df = df.unstack(level=0, fill_value=0).swaplevel(1,0, axis=1).sort_index(axis=1)
print (df)
endAt 2021-01-02        2021-01-03        2021-01-06        2021-01-07        \
           count    sum      count    sum      count    sum      count   sum   
id                                                                             
32             0    0.0          0    0.0          1  100.0          0   0.0   
619            0    0.0          0    0.0          0    0.0          0   0.0   
628            1  100.0          1  300.0          0    0.0          0   0.0   
629            0    0.0          0    0.0          0    0.0          1  50.0   

endAt 2021-01-08         
           count    sum  
id                       
32             0    0.0  
619            2  150.0  
628            0    0.0  
629            0    0.0
```

Sample data:

```
d = {'sum': {('2021-01-02', 628): 100.0, ('2021-01-03', 628): 300.0, ('2021-01-06', 32): 100.0, ('2021-01-07', 629): 50.0, ('2021-01-08', 619): 150.0}, 'count': {('2021-01-02', 628): 1, ('2021-01-03', 628): 1, ('2021-01-06', 32): 1, ('2021-01-07', 629): 1, ('2021-01-08', 619): 2}}

df = pd.DataFrame(d).rename_axis(['endAt','id'])
print (df)
                  sum  count
endAt      id               
2021-01-02 628  100.0      1
2021-01-03 628  300.0      1
2021-01-06 32   100.0      1
2021-01-07 629   50.0      1
2021-01-08 619  150.0      2
```

Comment: thank you. Yes, i am playing with unstack. Unfortunatel, swaplevel got error back "unexpected param axis" (what is strange to me). Can you show me how you initialized your df ?

Comment: @OcMaRUS - Added to answer.

Comment: ! Thank you! Yes, exactly what is needed. Now, i have to find out what wrong with my df, because your procedure is not working for.

Comment: @OcMaRUS - There is only `"unexpected param axis"` error? Maybe try upgdate pandas.

Comment: But your code works fine and no any error.

Comment: @OcMaRUS - Hmm, it means some data related problems. One idea - maybe is necessary `df.groupby(['endAt','id']).sum().unstack(level=0, fill_value=0).swaplevel(1,0, axis=1).sort_index(axis=1)`

Comment: both variants works fine :) something strange with my initial df. Your solution gave me the power to find the reason and solve the problem :) thanks!

Comment: probably, i found. Youd df is MultiIndexed by default (as defined). My df is simple df. So, I believe, i have to set MuliIndexes first somehow.

Comment: @OcMaRUS - Then try `df.set_index('id', append=True).unstack(level=0, fill_value=0).swaplevel(1,0, axis=1).sort_index(axis=1)`

Comment: Much appreciate your time and ideas!! Yes, I got the result! The problem was in incorrect indexes. It was important to set up right multiIndex df and last .sort_index - is very important also!